# MySQL available timeslots by staff ID

Tags: mysql

I want to run a MySQL query where it displays available time slots based on staff id (sid). I have found several queries but non seem to work. I have no idea where to even start with the query.

The goal is to display time slots based on a custom interval. 30 min interval example: (8:00, 8:30, 9:00) for a specific time range.

-OR-

Display "free from: 8AM to 5:00PM" for a specific time range.

How can I accomplish this?

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `currentTimeStamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `statuscode` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=253 ;


INSERT INTO `appointments` (`id`, `cid`, `sid`, `bid`, `start`, `end`, `currenttimestamp`, `status`) VALUES
(238, 81, 1, 1, '2017-05-29 08:00:00', '2017-05-29 08:15:00', '2017-02-21 17:38:42', 'open'),
(241, 81, 1, 1, '2017-05-29 09:00:00', '2017-05-29 09:15:00', '2017-02-21 17:38:42', 'open'),
(245, 81, 2, 1, '2017-05-29 08:00:00', '2017-05-29 08:15:00', '2017-02-21 17:38:42', 'open'),
(246, 81, 2, 1, '2017-05-29 09:00:00', '2017-05-29 09:45:00', '2017-02-21 17:38:42', 'open'),
(247, 81, 2, 1, '2017-05-29 12:00:00', '2017-05-29 12:45:00', '2017-02-21 17:38:42', 'open'),
(250, 81, 3, 1, '2017-05-29 09:00:00', '2017-05-29 09:45:00', '2017-02-21 17:38:42', 'open');

SELECT id, staff, business, free_from, free_until
FROM (
  SELECT a.id AS id, a.sid AS staff, a.bid AS business, a.end AS free_from,
  (SELECT MIN(c.start)
   FROM appointments c
   WHERE c.start > a.end) as free_until
  FROM appointments a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM appointments b
    WHERE b.start BETWEEN a.end AND a.end + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
  )
  AND a.end BETWEEN '2017-05-29 08:00:00' AND '2017-05-29 17:00:00'
) AS timeslots
WHERE staff = 2
ORDER BY free_until
```

Comment: So have you tried something other than just creating table and inserting data?

Comment: Like I said, I have found several queries but non seem to work. The closest one I found displays "free from" "free until" but it only displays up to the last appointment when selecting a specific staff Id. If I leave the staff ID blank, time slots shows correctly.